# how to Customer table antd formatNumber

Tags: reactjs, redux

https://ant.design/components/table/
[image]

I want to convert numbers to money using Table antd In line with this example I'm so confused, please help me, I hurry because I have to submit the last project before I graduate.

const timeConverter = rawDate => moment(rawDate).tz("Thai/Bangkok").format('L');

```
  const { pagination } = this.props;
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "ID",
      dataIndex: "id",
      align: "center",
      width: "60px",
      height: "30px",
    },
    {
      title:"วันที่บันทึก",
      dataIndex:"createdAt",
      align:"center",
      width:"200",
      format:"0,0",
      render: createdAt => timeConverter(createdAt)
    },
    {
      title:"อ้างอิงใบเสร็จเลขที่ ",
      dataIndex:"re_reference",
      align:"center",
      width:"200"
    },
    {
      title:"ชื่อบริการ/สินค้า",
      dataIndex:"re_pro_name",
      align:"center",
      width:"350",
    },
    {
      title:"รายละเอียด",
      dataIndex:"re_detail",
      align:"center",
      width:"100",
    },
    {
      title:"รหัสสมาชิก (ถ้ามี)",
      dataIndex:"re_cus_name",
      align:"center",
      width:"200",
    },
    {
      title:"ประเภทรับ-จ่าย",
      dataIndex:"re_type",
      align:"center",
      width:"350",
    },
    {
      title:"ราคาต่อหน่วย",
      dataIndex:"re_price",
      align:"center",
      width:"300",
      // render: re_price => numeral('$0,0.00')(re_price)
      render:(text, record) => (
        <span> </span>
      )
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

render: value =>  `${value}.00`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') //convert number monney